# Read and write from standard I\O streams causes error

Tags: c++, io, stl, stream, iterator

Why this cause my program to finish with following exit code

```
deque<int> di((istream_iterator<int>(cin)), (istream_iterator<int>()));
copy(di.begin(), di.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

> The thread 0x5d4 has exited with code -1073741749 (0xc000004b).
>
> The program '[3776] Josuttis.exe' has exited with code -1073741510
>   (0xc000013a).

EDIT:

This error i have during program execution:

[image: Error i got]

Actually, enter "1 1 1 1 9 Ctrl+C". May be Ctrl+C is wrong here?

EDIT2:
Ouch, i think it is because of Ctrl+C - [CTRL+C (Break)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540312(v=vs.85).aspx), *Sorry for bothering you!*

Comment: Looks like a crash to me, please try to run in a debugger and locate the crash. Are you sure it happens on one of those two lines shown?

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bcaeb59ff81e6d7)

Answer (score 3):

Just because your program crashed on a particular line doesn't mean that's where the bug is. Although the cited code fragment is slightly ...odd, technically I see nothing wrong with it.

The bug could've occured anywhere else, previously, where memory got corrupted, which eventually results in a crash at this particular point.